# Checking to see if name is already in list

Tags: vb.net

I have a dialog box which asks for details of a customer, they are saved as a list

```
Private fNames As List(Of String)
```

I have a method which checks to see if the name is in the list and returns true if they are and false if they are not.

```
Public Function isNameInList(ByVal myName As String) As Boolean
   Return fNames.Contains(myName)
End Function
```

If the returned value is false the name is added.

```
Public Sub addName(ByVal myName As String)
        If isNameInList(myName) = False Then
            fNames.Add(myName)
        End If
End Sub
```

The name is added to the list and is further displayed in a list box. I go to add the same name and it again is added to the list box when it shouldn't be. Have I missed something?

Comment: Are the "same" names all in the same case?  In VB.Net "Bob" and "bob" are not equal.  I don't see an issue with what you have here.  Can you show us your code that calls addName?

Comment: `have i missed something` Punctuation.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. Noted and will never let it happen again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use a `List` you probably want to use a `Set` such as a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

`Sets` by definition do not allow duplicates and are very similar in use to `Lists`. If a set already contains a value, `Add` will return false and the value will simply not be added. If it is still added, then the values are not exactly identical (as defined by the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods).

---

Note: `Equals` for Strings is case and white-space sensitive, so you will probably need to `Trim` the String and convert to one case or use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` when comparing.

```
myString.Trim().Equals(myOtherString.Trim(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

If you wish to do more work, you can even write your own `StringComparer`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with "homework" questions, is that he was probably told to use a List.  Unfortunately professors don't always keep their curriculum up-to-date with the best methods available.

Answer (score 1):

The comparision is case sensitive. This means that "Joe" and "joe" are different and will both be added. Could this be your problem?

I have tested your code. It seems to work. However you are also talking about a list box. Are you doing something wrong there?

---

If you declare your list as `System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of String)` instead of `List(Of String)` and then assign this list to the listbox like this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = fNames
```

then the new names will automatically be displayed in the ListBox when you add them to fNames.